# Citrix does not work after Opensuse Update; how to narrow down the issue?

Tags: opensuse, citrix-receiver

I am using the Citrix Receiver under OpenSuse 13.1. I made an system update this weekend and realized, that the Receiver does not start anymore, when I launch the shortcut on the according website, where I want to connect to. 
I also tried to start the Citrix Receiver just by KLauncher, which did not work. Unfortunately I do not get any error messages, so I do not really know, where to start.

I remember that it took a pretty big effort to actually get to run the client under OpenSuse and I found the old hint webpage I probably used:
http://www.itswapshop.com/tutorial/how-install-citrix-receiver-linux-120-opensuse-121

So I have a couple of questions to narrow down the problem, why it stopped running after the update:

Is it possible to get a log of the last system update(s) made? I did restart, so I do not have it in my bash history anymore.

Where are the Certificates of Firefox hidden now? There do not seem to be in the mozilla directory anymore. Although I do not think, this would be the problem as I remember I got a certificate error, when they were not corretly implemented.

Thanks!

Edit:
Ok, nevermind: I installed openmotif and then I realized, that Firefox wants to be pleased to open the addon and even shows a symbol next to the URL. But this is really not eye-catching...

Answer (score 2):

Certificates are now found in /usr/share/pki/trust/
But you need to convert all .pem certificates to .crt :

```
for file in *.pem ; do openssl x509 -outform der -in "$file" -out "$(echo "$file" | sed 's/\.pem/\.crt/')" ; done
```

See: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/499168-Citrix-Error-61-%28-quot-not-chosen-to-trust-quot-%29-All-files-and-certificates-seem-to-be-correct